# definindo tamanhos de acordo com o carregamento completo, ou resize de uma página

Tags: javascript, css

Bom, estou tentando definir um width de acordo com o width da tela do browser do usuário, porém, no console não é apontado nenhum erro, mas o código também não roda

```
var bannersWidth = document.querySelectorAll(".banner-holder .carousel figure");
for(var i = 0; i < bannersWidth; i++){
    bannersWidth[i].style.width == window.offsetWidth + "px";
}
```

- Sei que está fora de uma `document.onload` ou `window.onresize` (vou colocar dentro após a conclusão do script)

O que há de errado, por que está errado e como posso corrigir ?

Comment: `figure { max-width: 100% }` não atende ?

Comment: não vou usar o max-width, pois preciso posicionar várias, uma seguida da outra, para um carousel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma alternativa para fazer isso seria definir a largura dos banners da seguinte maneira:

```
.banner-holder{
   width:100%;
} 
.carousel figure{
   width:100%;
}
```

Ou ao invés de definir o `css`, pega direto a largura da janela `window.innerWidth`

```
for(var i = 0; i < bannersWidth.length; i++){
    bannersWidth[i].style.width == window.innerWidth + "px";
}
```

*Nota que o objeto [Window](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_window.asp) não possui a propriedade `offsetWidth`, possivelmente é por isso que não funciona.

*Também não funcionará `screen.width` pois o mesmo retorna a largura da **tela** e de acordo com a pergunta tu quer a largura do browser.

Segue um exemplo funcional:

```js
function AjustaLarguras() {
  var bannersWidth = document.querySelectorAll(".banner-holder,.carousel,.figure");
  for (var i = 0; i < bannersWidth.length; i++) {
    bannersWidth[i].style.width = window.offsetWidth + "px";
  }
}
```

```css
.banner-holder {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.carousel {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

.figure {
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<body onload="AjustaLarguras()">
  <div class="banner-holder">
  </div>
  <div class="carousel">
  </div>
  <div class="figure">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Não rodou :/ o "bannersWidth[i]" não está recebendo o valor, nenhum erro é apontado no console

Comment: acho que encontrei o erro, "bannersWidth" sem o ".length"

Comment: @MuriloGambôa coloquei um exemplo na resposta, espero que ajude.